# Rounded layout with rounded buttons in his corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-custom-view

Last time I've implemented popup context menu with 'rounded flat design', which looks similar to this:
[image]
First picture presents just showed menu, and at the second and third pictures present button color when it is pressed and selected.

When I worked on it I've met following problem - even I rounded layout (parent view), button doesn't care and its background is still a rectangle (color state is stored as selector xml). My solution for this problem was to prepare few kinds of styles for situations which I need, e.g. left-top corner, right-top and bottom corners and apply it to layput xml.

Unfortunately this approach is completely inflexible. If I want to hide one view I have to remember to check which buttons will be in the corners now.

I'm just wondering, is there some better solution? Where should I looking for? Create my custom layout for buttons/parent layout, or maybe should I read more about animations?

I will really appreciate any tips.

Comment: "If I want to hide one view I have to remember to check which buttons will be in the corners now." - you are pretty much going to have to do this anyway. I don't believe that there's anything that will automatically update the buttons' backgrounds based on their location, unless you write it yourself.

Comment: Ok, so if I would like to implement this feature by myself, where should I start? 
I suppose that I should create custom layout and I think I will try to develop it in this way.

Comment: I had to implement something similar for buttons in a curved alert dialog box. It could either have one button (curved corners @ bottom left and bottom right), two buttons (each with one curved corner), or three buttons (middle button with no curved corners). I simply wrote code that determined where a button will be added in the layout and set its background accordingly. In your case, you will obviously have to have many backgrounds available for each button type. Just make sure to use the correct ones based on the buttons' positions.